# Не адаптируются под разрешения дочерние объекты, объекта с grid layout group unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Создаю дочерние префабы у объекта с grid layout group с помощью скрипта, но при изменении разрешения, они становятся или очень маленькими или очень большие, смотрел уроки по нему, почему то в них всегда элементы адаптируются под разрешение экрана

Скрипт на создание объектов:

```
for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
    {
        GameObject obj = Instantiate(BobblePref[Random.Range(1,6)]);
        obj.transform.SetParent(Grid, false);
        //obj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.9f,0.9f,0);
        
    }
}
```

Настройки grid layout group

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю почему так происходит, что можно предпринять в данной ситуации или возможно где то допустил ошибку

Comment: [Canvas Scaler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@2.0/manual/script-CanvasScaler.html)

Comment: Пробовал, все остается так же